# Timeout while installing istio-ingress helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am trying to install istio-ingress helm chart but the command times out after 5 minutes with `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition`.

This is a bare-metal k8s installation with the following initial configuration:

```yaml
# kubeadm-config.yaml
kind: ClusterConfiguration
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kubernetesVersion: v1.27.3
networking:
  podSubnet: "10.3.0.0/24"
---
kind: KubeletConfiguration
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
cgroupDriver: systemd
serverTLSBootstrap: true
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: "192.168.1.200"
```

Calico has been installed, the node is ready and all noSchedule taints have been removed.

Istio installation takes place as such:

```bash
kubectl create namespace istio-system
helm install istio-base istio/base -n istio-system --set defaultRevision=default
helm install istiod istio/istiod -n istio-system --wait
kubectl create namespace istio-ingress
helm install istio-ingress istio/gateway -n istio-ingress --wait
```

The last command (installation of istio-ingress) times out after 5 minutes even though the pod is up and running almost immediately:

```bash
kubectl -n istio-ingress get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-ingress-6f9c5dd58d-ws47n   1/1     Running   0          11m
```

I am also attaching the pod log output for your reference:

```bash
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452604Z info    FLAG: --concurrency="0"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452630Z info    FLAG: --domain="istio-ingress.svc.cluster.local"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452637Z info    FLAG: --help="false"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452641Z info    FLAG: --log_as_json="false"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452643Z info    FLAG: --log_caller=""
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452645Z info    FLAG: --log_output_level="default:info"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452647Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate=""
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452649Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_age="30"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452651Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_backups="1000"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452653Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_size="104857600"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452656Z info    FLAG: --log_stacktrace_level="default:none"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452669Z info    FLAG: --log_target="[stdout]"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452675Z info    FLAG: --meshConfig="./etc/istio/config/mesh"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452677Z info    FLAG: --outlierLogPath=""
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452679Z info    FLAG: --profiling="true"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452682Z info    FLAG: --proxyComponentLogLevel="misc:error"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452684Z info    FLAG: --proxyLogLevel="warning"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452689Z info    FLAG: --s2a_enable_appengine_dialer="false"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452697Z info    FLAG: --s2a_timeout="3s"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452699Z info    FLAG: --serviceCluster="istio-proxy"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452701Z info    FLAG: --stsPort="0"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452703Z info    FLAG: --templateFile=""
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452706Z info    FLAG: --tokenManagerPlugin="GoogleTokenExchange"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452711Z info    FLAG: --vklog="0"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.452715Z info    Version 1.18.0-697f4ff0fe6ee531bbd4f5f2a6b4b1f302c955a8-Clean
2023-07-11T16:38:58.454063Z info    Maximum file descriptors (ulimit -n): 1048576
2023-07-11T16:38:58.454190Z info    Proxy role  ips=[10.3.0.73] type=router id=istio-ingress-6f9c5dd58d-ws47n.istio-ingress domain=istio-ingress.svc.cluster.local
2023-07-11T16:38:58.454263Z info    Apply proxy config from env {}

2023-07-11T16:38:58.455674Z info    cpu limit detected as 2, setting concurrency
2023-07-11T16:38:58.456000Z info    Effective config: binaryPath: /usr/local/bin/envoy
concurrency: 2
configPath: ./etc/istio/proxy
controlPlaneAuthPolicy: MUTUAL_TLS
discoveryAddress: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
drainDuration: 45s
proxyAdminPort: 15000
serviceCluster: istio-proxy
statNameLength: 189
statusPort: 15020
terminationDrainDuration: 5s
tracing:
  zipkin:
    address: zipkin.istio-system:9411

2023-07-11T16:38:58.456014Z info    JWT policy is third-party-jwt
2023-07-11T16:38:58.456018Z info    using credential fetcher of JWT type in cluster.local trust domain
2023-07-11T16:38:58.556999Z info    Workload SDS socket not found. Starting Istio SDS Server
2023-07-11T16:38:58.557042Z info    CA Endpoint istiod.istio-system.svc:15012, provider Citadel
2023-07-11T16:38:58.557091Z info    Using CA istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 cert with certs: var/run/secrets/istio/root-cert.pem
2023-07-11T16:38:58.557044Z info    Opening status port 15020
2023-07-11T16:38:58.588781Z info    ads All caches have been synced up in 138.78523ms, marking server ready
2023-07-11T16:38:58.589447Z info    xdsproxy    Initializing with upstream address "istiod.istio-system.svc:15012" and cluster "Kubernetes"
2023-07-11T16:38:58.590241Z info    sds Starting SDS grpc server
2023-07-11T16:38:58.590767Z info    starting Http service at 127.0.0.1:15004
2023-07-11T16:38:58.592773Z info    Pilot SAN: [istiod.istio-system.svc]
2023-07-11T16:38:58.594066Z info    Starting proxy agent
2023-07-11T16:38:58.594113Z info    starting
2023-07-11T16:38:58.594157Z info    Envoy command: [-c etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev.json --drain-time-s 45 --drain-strategy immediate --local-address-ip-version v4 --file-flush-interval-msec 1000 --disable-hot-restart --allow-unknown-static-fields --log-format %Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ   %l  envoy %n %g:%#  %v  thread=%t -l warning --component-log-level misc:error --concurrency 2]
2023-07-11T16:38:58.656700Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2023-07-11T16:38:58.675422Z info    ads ADS: new connection for node:istio-ingress-6f9c5dd58d-ws47n.istio-ingress-1
2023-07-11T16:38:58.675907Z info    ads ADS: new connection for node:istio-ingress-6f9c5dd58d-ws47n.istio-ingress-2
2023-07-11T16:38:58.987742Z info    cache   generated new workload certificate  latency=397.583386ms ttl=23h59m59.012280135s
2023-07-11T16:38:58.987799Z info    cache   Root cert has changed, start rotating root cert
2023-07-11T16:38:58.987825Z info    ads XDS: Incremental Pushing:0 ConnectedEndpoints:2 Version:
2023-07-11T16:38:58.987950Z info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache   ttl=23h59m59.012056127s
2023-07-11T16:38:58.987981Z info    cache   returned workload certificate from cache    ttl=23h59m59.012027822s
2023-07-11T16:38:58.988133Z info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache   ttl=23h59m59.011879258s
2023-07-11T16:38:58.988273Z info    ads SDS: PUSH request for node:istio-ingress-6f9c5dd58d-ws47n.istio-ingress resources:1 size:4.0kB resource:default
2023-07-11T16:38:58.988439Z info    ads SDS: PUSH request for node:istio-ingress-6f9c5dd58d-ws47n.istio-ingress resources:1 size:1.1kB resource:ROOTCA
2023-07-11T16:38:58.988601Z info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache   ttl=23h59m59.011410512s
2023-07-11T16:38:59.893734Z info    Readiness succeeded in 1.448696062s
2023-07-11T16:38:59.894386Z info    Envoy proxy is ready
```

Comment: Checking events in istio-system namespace will a clue why installation is failing.